# Improve JDBC Performance

Tags: java, sql, multithreading, jdbc

I am executing the following set of statements in my java application. It connects to a oracle database.

```
stat=connection.createStatement();
stat1=commection.createstatement();
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(BIGQUERY);
while(rs.next()) {
    obj1.setAttr1(rs.getString(1));
    obj1.setAttr2(rs.getString(1));
    obj1.setAttr3(rs.getString(1));
    obj1.setAttr4(rs.getString(1));

    ResultSet rs1 = stat1.executeQuery(SMALLQ1);
    while(rs1.next()) {
       obj1.setAttr5(rs1.getString(1));
    }

     ResultSet rs2 = stat1.executeQuery(SMALLQ2);
    while(rs2.next()) {
       obj1.setAttr6(rs2.getString(1));

    }
         .
         .
         .
 LinkedBlockingqueue.add(obj1);
 }
 //all staements and connections close
```

The `BIGQUERY` returns around 4.5 million records  and for each record, I have to execute the smaller queries, which are 14 in number. Each small query has 3 inner join statements.

My multi threaded application now can process 90,000 in one hour. But I may have to run the code daily, so I want to process all the records in 20 hours. I am using about 200 threads which process the above code and stores the records in linked blocking queue.

Does increasing the thread count blindly helps increase the performance or is there some other way in which I can increase the performance of the result sets?

PS : I am unable to post the query here, but I am assured that all queries are optimized.

Comment: Why are you implementing the join in Java? The database will do that much more efficiently.

Comment: I am sorry, should've been clear. the BIGQUERY is a sql statement which has joins and I am just executing it.

Comment: if you could replace this with an oracle procedure, you'd save the time you're transferring the data from the server to your code.

Comment: I'm not talking about joins in bigquery. Your code implements a nested loop join between bigquery and smallq1 and another nested loop join between bigquery and smallq2. Something the database can do _much_ more efficiently than any solution you create with Java/JDBC (Oracle can also do the multithreading for you). Running a sql statement inside a loop for each iteration of the loop should ring a **lot** of alarm bells.

Comment: I assume your BIGQRY and SMALLQRYx have features and dependencies not easily implemented pure sql, thats why you make client-side juggling. Could you batch multiple SMALLQRYx to a same query statement? JdbcDriver+DB may not support returning multiple resultsets, but use "SELECT 1 as smallidx, col1, col2..UNION ALL..SELECT 2 as smallidx, col1, col2..." if smalls are more or less similar select queries?

Comment: You should avoid doing database query inside a loop.  This is a last resort if there is no way to do a join at the database level.

Comment: okay. You suggest it'll be lot faster if I can replace everything with one stored proc / query and retrieving the rows from the result of that ?

Comment: the small queries are of the following type : 

select attr1, attr2, attr3 from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.attr1=t2.attr1 and t2.attr2='VALUE1'
inner join table3 t3 on t1.attr1=t3.attr1 and t3.attr2='VALUE2'
and t1.attr3='VALUE3'


select attr1, attr2, attr3 from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.attr1=t2.attr1 and t2.attr2='VALUE4'
inner join table3 t3 on t1.attr1=t3.attr1 and t3.attr2='VALUE5'
and t1.attr3='VALUE6';

Comment: For your select statements you should check if required indexes exist. You can display the query execution plan using `EXPLAIN PLAN`. Check [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm#16889) for more information.

Comment: Try UNIONALL_BATCH trick if makes difference, extracol tells client loop where that row belongs to. select 1 as smallidx, attr1, attr2, attr3 
from table1 t1 
  inner join table2 t2 on t1.attr1=t2.attr1 and t2.attr2='VALUE1' 
  inner join table3 t3 on t1.attr1=t3.attr1 and t3.attr2='VALUE2' and t1.attr3='VALUE3' 
UNION ALL
select 2 as smallidx, attr1, attr2, attr3 
from table1 t1 
  inner join table2 t2 on t1.attr1=t2.attr1 and t2.attr2='VALUE4' 
  inner join table3 t3 on t1.attr1=t3.attr1 and t3.attr2='VALUE5' and t1.attr3='VALUE6'
UNION ALL
...VALUE7+VALUE8+VALUE9

Answer (score 8):

To improve JDBC performance for your scenario you can apply some modifications.

As you will see, all these modifications can significantly speed your task.

**1. Using batch operations.**

You can read your big query and store results in some kind of buffer.
And only when buffer is full you should run subquery for all data collected in buffer.
This significantly reduces number of SQL statements to execute.

```
static final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000; 
List<MyData> buffer = new ArrayList<>(BATCH_SIZE);

while (rs.hasNext()) {

  MyData record = new MyData( rs.getString(1), ..., rs.getString(4) );
  buffer.add( record );

  if (buffer.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
    processBatch( buffer );
  }  
}

void processBatch( List<MyData> buffer ) {

  String sql = "select ... where X and id in (" + getIDs(buffer) + ")";
  stat1.executeQuery(sql);  // query for all IDs in buffer
  while(stat1.hasNext()) { ... }
  ...  
}
```

**2. Using efficient maps to store content from many selects.**

If your records are no so big you can store them all at once event for 4 mln table.

I used this approach many times for night processes (with no normal users).
Such approach may need much heap memory (i.e. 100 MB - 1 GB) - but is much faster that approach 1).

To do that you need efficient map implementation, i.e. - gnu.trove.map.TIntObjectMap (etc)
which is much better that java standard library maps.

```
final TIntObjectMap<MyData> map = new TIntObjectHashMap<MyData>(10000, 0.8f);

// query 1
while (rs.hasNext()) {
  MyData record = new MyData( rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), ..., rs.getString(4) );
  map.put(record.getId(), record);
}

// query 2
while (rs.hasNext()) {
  int id = rs.getInt(1);   // my data id
  String x = rs.getString(...);
  int y = rs.getInt(...);

  MyData record = map.get(id);
  record.add( new MyDetail(x,y) );
}

// query 3
// same pattern as query 2
```

After this you have map filled with all data collected. Probably with a lot of memory allocated. 
This is why you can use that method only if you hava such resources.

Another topic is how to write MyData and MyDetail classes to be as small as possible. 
You can use some tricks:

1. storing 3 integers (with limited range) in 1 long variable (using util for bit shifting)
2. storing Date objects as integer (yymmdd)
3. calling str.intern() for each string fetched from DB

**3. Transactions**

If you have to do some updates or inserts than 4 mln records is too much to handle in on transactions.
This is too much for most database configurations.
Use approach 1) and commit transaction for each batch.
On each new inserted record you can have something like RUN_ID and if everything went well you can mark this RUN_ID as successful.

If your queries only read - there is no problem. However you can mark transaction as Read-only to help your database.

**4. Jdbc fetch size.**

When you load a lot of records from database it is very, very important to set proper fetch size on your jdbc connection.
This reduces number of physical hits to database socket and speeds your process.

Example:

```
// jdbc
statement.setFetchSize(500);

// spring     
JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
jdbc.setFetchSize(500);
```

Here you can find some **benchmarks** and patterns for using fetch size:

http://makejavafaster.blogspot.com/2015/06/jdbc-fetch-size-performance.html

**5. PreparedStatement**

Use PreparedStatement rather than Statement.

**6. Number of sql statements.**

Always try to minimize number of sql statements you send to database.

Comment: I strongly disagree with #3 - in Oracle it is almost always faster to do everything in a single transaction rather than splitting it up into smaller chunks. Oracle is not SQL Server.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, you're right, most tasks Oracle do better in one TX, but there are some cases that task is too big for  current REDO LOG configuration, and i was talking about such case. In that cases I usually split task to smaller TXs with logic marker. Anyway I am Oracle enthusiast :)

Comment: Restrictions on the size of the redo log have nothing do do with performance. And as the whole problem is (only) about queries, not DML, redo logs will almost certainly not be a problem here.

Comment: I was writing more generally - if only queries than ok (maybe read-only tx). But if DML - the size of TX does matter as all TX redo records have to be stored.

Comment: I am mostly agree on the optimizations in this answer.  However, the very first thing we should do, before doing any of these optimization is to do some basic profiling to find out what are the time-taking logics.  Is it the query itself not written effectively? Is it fetching that took most time? etc.

Comment: @AdrianShum you're right, profiling gives you diagnosis, and after that you can apply appropiate medicine, i agree

Comment: Among all the suggestions, I think setting the right fetch size would have the biggest performance impact

Answer (score 4):

Try this
`resultSet.setFetchSize(100);`

`while(resultSet.next) {
...
}`

> The parameter is the number of rows that should be retrieved from the
>   database in each roundtrip